# how can I remove the gray tint overlay on guided access?

Tags: ios, guided-access

I am trying to completely disable touch on my ipad, and I am able to do this with guided access, except it puts a ridiculous gray tint over the entire screen.  There is no option that I can see to turn this off, is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

When you de-activate Guided Access, you should be able to see (after entering your passcode) a kind of menu. In the bottom-left corner of the screen, click on the "Options" button. In there, there should be an option called "Touch" which is, by default, enabled. Just disable it and touch will be disabled on your whole iPad screen (and you won't see the grey overlay) when you start Guided Access again.

[image]

<sup>The above screenshot (annotated by me) is from [How to use Guided Access on iPad | Apple Support - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JkDtljBD1Fw)</sup>